# Barra de rolagem na horizontal com bootstrap 4

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

Meus caros, meu site está estourando nas laterais gerando uma barra de rolagem inferior e ao lado da borda direita está uma parte toda branca.
Não consigo enxergar onde está o erro.
Segue um print do que está havendo.
[image: Erro]

Segue agora o meu código html e css:

```css
/*.topo{
    position: relative;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 450px;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    padding: 0;
}*/
html, body, main{ margin:0; height: 100%;width: 100%;}
header{
    background: url("img/love.jpg") no-repeat center top fixed;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
    height: 70%;
}
.logo{
    font-family: 'Great Vibes', cursive;
}
.titulo-section {
    font-family: 'Great Vibes', cursive;
    font-size: 40px;
    text-align: center;
    position: relative;
    top: 30px;
}
.pos-h1{
    position: relative;
    top: 40px;
}
.rodape{
    position: relative;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 100px;
    background-color: #1f1f1f;
    color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
}
.nossos-momentos, .nossos-padrinhos, .making-off, .blog, .lista-de-presentes, .single{
    position: relative;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 600px;
    background-color: #ffffff;
    color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
}
.nossa-historia, .dedicatoria, .manual-dos-padrinhos, .cerimonia, .contribua, .agenda, .single-agenda{
    position: relative;
    top: 0px;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 600px;
    background-color: #2e2e2e;
    color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
}
.home{
    position: relative;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 140px;
    background-color: #2e2e2e;
    color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
}
.titulo{
    width: 500px;
    height: 150px;
    border-radius: 500px;
    background-color: rgba(46, 46, 46, 0.5);
    color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
    position: absolute;
    box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #000;
    margin-left: -250px;
    left: 50%;
    margin-top: 445px;
    font-family: 'Great Vibes', cursive;
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="pt-br">
    <head>
        <title>Maria & João</title>
        <!-- Required meta tags -->
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
        <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-PsH8R72JQ3SOdhVi3uxftmaW6Vc51MKb0q5P2rRUpPvrszuE4W1povHYgTpBfshb" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
        <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Great+Vibes" rel="stylesheet">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="jpagination/jpagination.min.css">
        <link href="lightbox2/src/css/lightbox.css" rel="stylesheet">        
    </head>
    <body>        
        <main>
            <header class="bgParallax" data-speed="15">
                <div class="content">
                <nav class="navbar fixed-top navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark">
                    <a class="navbar-brand logo" href="index.html"><i class="fas fa-heart"></i> Maria & João</a>
                    <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                    </button>
                    
                    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
                        <ul class="navbar-nav mx-auto">
                            <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                                    <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                                        Os Noivos
                                    </a>
                                    <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
                                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="nossa-historia.html">Nossa História</a>
                                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="nossos-momentos.html">Nossos Momentos</a>
                                        <a class="dropdown-item" href="dedicatoria.html">Dedicatória</a>
                                    </div>
                                </li>
                            <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                                <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                                    Nossos Padrinhos
                                </a>
                                <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
                                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="nossos-padrinhos.html">Nossos Padrinhos</a>
                                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="manual-dos-padrinhos.html">Manual dos Padrinhos</a>
                                </div>
                            </li>
                            <li class="nav-item">
                                    <a class="nav-link" href="cerimonia.html">Cerimônia</a>
                            </li>
                            <li class="nav-item">
                                    <a class="nav-link" href="making-off.html">Making Off</a>
                            </li>
                            <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                                <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="nos-presentei.html" id="navbarDropdown" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                                    Nos Presenteie
                                </a>
                                <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
                                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="lista-de-presentes.html">Lista de Presentes</a>
                                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="contribua.html">Contribua Com A Nossa Caixinha</a>
                                </div>
                            </li>
                            <li class="nav-item">
                                    <a class="nav-link" href="blog.html">Blog</a>
                                    </li>
                            <li class="nav-item">
                                    <a class="nav-link" href="agenda.html">Agenda</a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </nav>
                </div>
            </header>
                <style>
                    header{
                        background: url("img/age.jpg") no-repeat center top fixed;
                        -webkit-background-size: cover;
                        -moz-background-size: cover;
                        -o-background-size: cover;
                        background-size: cover;
                    }
                </style>
            <section id="agenda" class="agenda">
                <h1 class="titulo-section">
                    Agenda<br>
                    <small class="text-muted">Confira os nossos próximos compromissos</small>
                </h1>
                <div class="container pos-h1">                    
                    <div class="row  justify-content-center text-center">
                        <div class="col-6 col-md-3 item">
                            <a href="single-agenda.html">
                                <figure class="figure">
                                    <img src="img/a-1.jpg" class="img-fluid" alt="Responsive image">
                                    <figcaption class="figure-caption">
                                        <h4 class="display-4">02/02</h4>
                                        <h3 class="display-4">2018</h3>
                                        <p>Despedida de Solteiro</p>
                                    </figcaption>
                                </figure>
                            </a>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-6 col-md-3 item">
                            <a href="single-agenda.html">
                                <figure class="figure">
                                    <img src="img/a-2.jpg" class="img-fluid" alt="Responsive image">
                                    <figcaption class="figure-caption">
                                        <h4 class="display-4">02/02</h4>
                                        <h3 class="display-4">2018</h3>
                                        <p>Jantar com os padrinhos</p>
                                    </figcaption>
                                </figure>
                            </a>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-6 col-md-3 item">
                            <a href="single-agenda.html">
                                <figure class="figure">
                                    <img src="img/a-3.jpg" class="img-fluid" alt="Responsive image">
                                    <figcaption class="figure-caption">
                                        <h4 class="display-4">02/02</h4>
                                        <h3 class="display-4">2018</h3>
                                        <p>Audição dos músicos</p>
                                    </figcaption>                            
                                </figure>
                            </a>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-6 col-md-3 item">
                            <a href="single-agenda.html">
                                <figure class="figure">
                                    <img src="img/a-4.jpg" class="img-fluid" alt="Responsive image">
                                    <figcaption class="figure-caption">
                                        <h4 class="display-4">02/02</h4>
                                        <h3 class="display-4">2018</h3>
                                        <p>O Grande dia</p>
                                    </figcaption>
                                </figure>
                            </a>
                        </div>
                    </div>                 
                </div>
                <br>
                <div class="row justify-content-center"><ul class = "pagination" id = "pagination"></ul></div>
                <br>
            </section>
            <footer>
                <section id="rodape" class="rodape">
                    <br>
                    <div class="content">
                        <div class="row justify-content-center">
                            <div class="col-8 text-center">
                                <p>Copyright © 2017 Sites Para Casamentos - Todos os direitos reservados</p>
                                <p>Contato: 31 99271-6979 | evertonrodrigues16@yahoo.com.br</p>
                                <p>facebook.com/sitesparacasamentos</p>
                                <p>www.sitesparacasamentos.com.br</p>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>                
                </section>
                <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
                <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
                <script
                src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"
                integrity="sha256-hwg4gsxgFZhOsEEamdOYGBf13FyQuiTwlAQgxVSNgt4="
                crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
                <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.3/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-vFJXuSJphROIrBnz7yo7oB41mKfc8JzQZiCq4NCceLEaO4IHwicKwpJf9c9IpFgh" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
                <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0-beta.2/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-alpBpkh1PFOepccYVYDB4do5UnbKysX5WZXm3XxPqe5iKTfUKjNkCk9SaVuEZflJ" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
                <script defer src="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.0.1/js/all.js"></script>
                <script src="jpagination/jpagination.js"></script>
                <script src="lightbox2/src/js/lightbox.js"></script>
                <script>
                    $('header.bgParallax').each(function(){
                    var $obj = $(this);
    
                        $(window).scroll(function() {
                            var yPos = -($(window).scrollTop() / $obj.data('speed')); 
    
                            var bgpos = '50% '+ yPos + 'px';
    
                            $obj.css('background-position', bgpos );
    
                        }); 
                    });
                </script>
                <script>
                    jQuery(document).ready(function(){generate('pagination', 4, 8)});
                </script>
            </footer>
        </main>        
    </body>
</html>
```

Aguardo a ajuda de vocês, obrigado!

Comment: Testei aqui e o erro persiste.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O problema está na `div` abaixo que está com duas `margin` `left` e `right` aumentando o elemento para além da largura da tela:

```
<div class="row justify-content-center"><ul class = "pagination" id = "pagination"></ul></div>
```

Para solucionar isso, inclua no seu CSS o código:

```
div.row.justify-content-center{
   margin: 0;
}
```

Comment: Congratulations!!!!!!!

Comment: Era isso mesmo, agradeço muito a sua ajuda. Será que podia me explicar como conseguiu chegar a conclusão para que nas próximas eu consiga também. Agradeço demais.

Answer (score 2):

**Por que isso acontece???**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Ele está aparecendo porque as larguras do seu contêiner são 1200px, se a largura da tela for menor do que isso ... bem, você terá uma barra de rolagem inferior.

Agora que você sabe porque isso acontece.

Vamos lá?

Você está usando Bootstrap certo! No seu código html tem  uma class chamada `row` está class possui 2 propriedades `bootstrap.min.css` que foram responsáveis por este efeito indesejado.
 `

```html
<div class="row justify-content-center"><ul class = "pagination" id = "pagination"></ul></div>
```

```
.row {
    margin-right: -15px;
    margin-left: -15px;
}
```

**Solução**

A maneira mais fácil é simplismente remover as margens.

```css
.row {
  margin-left: 0;
  margin-right: 0;
}
```

A outra solução seria refatora a sua estrutura no html usando um contêiner fluido removendo completamete a margen.

```html
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-6 col-md-3 item">
      <a href="single-agenda.html">
        <figure class="figure">
          <img src="img/a-2.jpg" class="img-fluid" alt="Responsive image">
          <figcaption class="figure-caption">
            <h4 class="display-4">02/02</h4>
            <h3 class="display-4">2018</h3>
            <p>Jantar com os padrinhos</p>
          </figcaption>
        </figure>
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Espero que tenho ajudado...